# Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException

Tags: php, firebase, guzzle

I'm working on Firebase Admin SDK with PHP kreait/firebase-php and It's going well on the realtime database. However, the authentication wherein I want to create users give me fatal error where it says:  **Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser` resulted in a `400 Bad Request`**

and I'm not experienced enough to know how to fix this. Here are my PHP codes and hope it helps.

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';


use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\Auth;

$factory = (new Factory)
    ->withServiceAccount('dazsma-test-firebase-adminsdk-xprg4-0bedd1e1e2.json')
    ->withDatabaseUri('https://dazsma-test-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/');
    
    $database = $factory->createDatabase();
    $auth = $factory->createAuth();


    
?>
```

the 2nd one

```
<?php
session_start();
include('dbcon.php');

if(isset($_POST['register_btn']))
{
    $fullname = $_POST['full_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $userProperties = [
        'email' => $email,
        'emailVerified' => false,
        'phoneNumber' => '+09'.$phone,
        'password' => $password,
        'displayName' => $fullname,
    ];
    
    $createdUser = $auth->createUser($userProperties);

    if($createdUser) 
    {
        $_SESSION['status'] = "User Created Successfully!";
        header('Location: register.php');
        exit();
    }
    else 
    {
        $_SESSION['status'] = "User Creation Failed!";
        header('Location: register.php');
        exit();
    }

}
```

and this is my register.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
include('includes/header.php');
?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-6">

        <?php 
                if(isset($_SESSION['status'])) {
                    echo "<h5 class='alert alert-success'>".$_SESSION['status']."</h5>";
                    unset($_SESSION['status']);
                }
            ?>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h4>
                        Create User
                        <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-danger float-end"> Back</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">

                <form action="code.php" method="POST">

                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label for="">Full Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="full_name" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label for="">Email Address</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label for="">Phone Number</label>
                        <input type="number" name="phone" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label for="">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <button type="submit" name="register_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                    </div>

                </form>

                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php 
include('includes/footer.php');
?>

**Please help, I'm in a rush.**
```

Answer (score -1):

The documentation has a section about error handling:

https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/5.x/troubleshooting.html#error-handling

Without knowing the inputs that you submit with the form, I see the following possible reasons:

- The password is too short
- The email is invalid
- The phone number is invalid

Catching the exception and inspecting it should give you the actual reason.